# How can I get selected items on listdialog's click event?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I am implementing listdialog. I want to print a toast message when I click on a particular listitem. I want to print message on toast or else I want to perform some action. My code is like this:

```
ListView lv;
DbHelper dbh;
final String ar[]={"Delete","Update"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    dbh = new DbHelper(ViewAllActivity.this);

    ArrayList<DoctorPojo> arraylist = dbh.getData();
    ArrayAdapter<DoctorPojo> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<DoctorPojo>(ViewAllActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {

            final AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewAllActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Which Action You Want to Perform...!!!");
            alert.setItems(ar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(ar[0] == alert.) {
                        Toast.makeText(ViewAllActivity.this, " Delete is pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ViewAllActivity.this, " Update is pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            alert.create().show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    }

}
```

Please help; I am confused about the if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to implement [ListView's setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) instead. setOnItemLongClickListener is used for pressing and holding down on the list item.

For ListView's setOnItemClickListener() implementation, you could do something like the following:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
             //YOUR ACTION HERE
             //or show a toast instead:
             Toast.makeText(ViewAllActivity.this, "Your message here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Exactly sir. Thank you for your support.